# How can I return the last element that fits under the criteria for driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a document that either has 1 or two links that can be found using the selenium/python command `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text`.  Whether it's one or two links, I always want the script to return the last in the list.

Is there any way to do this?

i.e. the page sometimes has a link with text stackoverflow.com/xxxxxxx and stackoverflow.com/iwantthislink.  Other times it just has stackoverflow.com/iwantthislink.

When I use `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("stackoverflow.com/")` it returns stackoverflow.com/xxxxxxx since it comes before stackoverflow.com/iwantthislink.

I just need a way to always return the last element in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_elements_by_partial_link_text` returns a list. (Notice `elements` vs `element`.)

To access the last element do:

```
my_elem = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('sometext')[-1]
```

Better yet, test the existence of the elements beforehand:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('sometext')
if elems:
    my_elem = elems[-1]
```